# Linq to XML - Get next element of sibling with specific value

Tags: linq, linq-to-xml

I've got an xml structure similar to this:

```
<cars>
  <car>
    <make>Ford</make>
    <model>F-150</model>
    <year>2011</year>
    <customs>
      <customAttribute>Color</customAttribute>
      <customValue>Black</customValue>
      <customAttribute>Doors</customAttribute>
      <customValue>2</customValue>
    </customs>
  </car>
</cars>
```

And I want to return a list of cars in a method that looks something like:

```
return (from car in cars.Descendants("car")
       select new Car {
           Make = car.Element("make").Value,
           Model = car.Element("model").Value,
           Year = car.Element("year").Value
           Color = ?????,
           Doors = ?????
       });
```

How can I populate the Color and Doors fields? I need to get the customAttribute value for the appropriate customValue node.

Not quite sure how to accomplish this.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your xml @line `<year>`, but...

This one should do the trick, few null checks would be, of course, better.

By the way, if Color (and Doors) were attributes instead of Nodes, it wouldn't be worse...

```
var result = cars.Descendants("car")
              .Select(car => new Car
                     {
                        Make = car.Element("make").Value,
                        Model = car.Element("model").Value,
                        Year = car.Element("year").Value,
                        Color = (car.Element("customs").Elements("customAttribute").First(m => m.Value == "Color").NextNode as XElement).Value,
                        Doors = (car.Element("customs").Elements("customAttribute").First(m => m.Value == "Doors").NextNode as XElement).Value
                     })
              .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks Raphaël, I've fixed the typo and added a new detail. the custom nodes actually have a parent node. any idea on how to incorporate that?

Comment: @ChrisConway Edited with your new requirement.